# How to get rid of the line on the right in gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

using gnuplot for the 1st time. Why is there this vertical line on the right (see picture)? Or the other way around: how do i get rid of it?

[image]

Edit: It seems to occur when not using autoscale. But since I don't want to use autoscale the problem remains the same for me.

Edit 2nd: My code

```
gnuplot> set yrange [0:4]
gnuplot> set xrange [0:51]
gnuplot> set title "Laufzeiten Main in der Praxis (1. Importer)" font "Times-New-Roman,12"
gnuplot> set ylabel "Dauer in Minuten" font "Times-New-Roman,12"
gnuplot> set xlabel "Durchlauf" font "Times-New-Roman,12"
gnuplot> replot
gnuplot> set pointsize 2
gnuplot> replot
```

I'm using a mac with terminal.

Comment: what is your code to produce this? What is you terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out: simply closing gnuplot and doing it again solved my problem. So sorry for bothering.